# SSH disconnect from VirtualBox because of too many connections

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox 4.1.12_Ubuntu on an Ubuntu 12.04 host. I'm getting disconnected from my VirtualBox (ssh connection if I execute the following bash script.

```
for i in {1..200}
do
  curl "http://doesnotexist"
done
```

Obviously, the script is not useful but it allows to reproduce the problem easily. The same script works (i.e. no disconnect) if the host of the VirtualBox is a Windows machine.

Any idea which Ubuntu/Linux limitation is triggering my ssh connection to be terminated?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How is the box connected? Bridge? NAT? What's the message when getting disconnected?

Comment: The box is connected bridged but we also tried NAT - same result.  It's important to note that it's not only the current ssh connection that is being disconnected but pretty much any connection to the box. The message is "Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.".

Answer (score 0):

I am right sure it's because Windows limits the concurrent "half-open" connections. That means, after starting this script, your windows box has 1 open ssh connection and another 15 half open to the host which doesn't exist.
Linux doesn't have this limitation, but seems to brake down because of so many connections.

You can try to disable the limit of windows to proof my theory: [Tool not tested!](http://half-open.com)

Comment: Did it help? Is there a solution?